# When installing oAuth I get a dependency error

Tags: oauth, ubuntu-12.04, php-5.6

I'm installing php oAuth in my Ubuntu 12.04 on PHP 5.6. I tried the following commands

```
apt-get update
apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev
apt-get install php5-oauth
```

I'm getting this error :

```
php5-oauth : Depends: phpapi-20121212
```

Also tried with pecl

```
pecl install oauth
pecl/oauth is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.2.3
install failed
```

I added `extension=oauth.so` in `php.ini` file and restarted Apache also.

I tried this command `pecl list`

```
Installed packages, channel pecl.php.net:
=========================================
Package Version State
mongo   1.1.4   stable
oauth   1.2.3   stable
```

It shows oauth is installed but it not showing `oAuth` in php info file.

Comment: Any suggestions please.